# pgfplot consistent number format

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I am trying to make a the number format in my `pgfplots` the same, as in the rest of my document. I am normally using the `\num` from the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/help/Catalogue/entries/siunitx.html) package to typeset numbers, and would like to use it in my plots as well.

`\num` does not produce the same format as `\pgfmathprintnumber`, and I have tried this (thanks @Jake and @Marco Daniel):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
    xmin=1, xmax=5000,
    ymin=0, ymax=2,
    log base 10 number format code/.code={ \pgfmathparse{10^(#1)}\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=0]{\pgfmathresult} },           %num version
    % log base 10 number format code/.code={$\pgfmathparse{10^(#1)}\pgfmathprintnumber[set thousands separator=\,]{\pgfmathresult}$}  %pgfmathprintnumber version
    % yticklabel={\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{\tick}} %does not work
    ]
    \node at (axis cs: 10, 1.8) {\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=0]{12345678}};
    \node at (axis cs: 10, 1.7) {\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect, set thousands separator=\,]{12345678}};    
    \node at (axis cs: 10, 1.4) {\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=0]{1000}};
    \node at (axis cs: 10, 1.3) {\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect, set thousands separator=\,]{1000}};    
  \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Show number format]

When ymax<3, the code for the yticklabel give the compile error:

```
! Number too big. \l_siunitx_tmpa_tl ->5000000000
```

Is there a solution to this problem, or some way to set the global number format used by `pgfplots`?

---

Here is the minimumcode, that is failing:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
    xmin=1, xmax=5000,
    ymin=0, ymax=2,
    yticklabel={\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{\tick}} %does not work
    ]
  \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried fiddling about with your code, and can't reproduce the fault. Could you edit the question so that there is one 'works' code block and one 'fails': this makes it a bit easier to follow the issues.

Comment: @JosephWright: Done:o)

Comment: @JosephWright: I can reproduce the error by changing `ymax` to `3` and uncommenting the `yticklabel` line. The problem seems to be that the rounding algorithm stumbles if you give it too many trailing zeros: PGFplots passes `1.5000000000000`. You can get the same error message with the minimal example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[round-mode=places]{1.5000000000000}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Jake Currently, the rounding code uses TeX's number comparisons, _etc._ for speed. There's a balance between performance and flexibility. (How many people need to round really large numbers of digits?) I can take another look at this part of the code and see what I can do: may take a little while.

Comment: I've logged this issue: https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issue/186/rounding-code-assumes-tex-safe-numbers-in. Hopefully I can fix it over the Christmas holiday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this happens because the tick value is sometimes defined with a lot of trailing zeros, which causes a `dimension too large` error when `siunitx` tries to round the value. As a workaround, you could let `\pgfmathparse` clean up the value first by parsing it using `\pgfmathparse{\tick*1}` and then letting `\num` do its thing with `\pgfmathresult`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}
    [
    xmin=1, xmax=5000,
    ymin=0, ymax=2,
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{(\tick*1)}\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}}
    ]
  \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the '*1' because pgfmathparse insist on doing something?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: No, it's because `\pgfmathparse` would just leave the number untouched if there's no operation.

Comment: hi, this helps with numbers, were ```\pgfmathparse``` cleanes up the number, but how could this help with a number that is really to large? Which gets replaced with 2147483647 because that's the largest possible number? (not sure for which package)