# siunitx number too big when trying to round

Tags: tables, siunitx

Using the `siunitx` package

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

I am trying to put numbers with plenty of decimal digits in a table while rounding them to 3 digits after the decimal point. There is a compilation error saying `! Number too big.`. I tried to change the expected digit amounts to a thousand, but this does not work:

```
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{
    table-number-alignment = center,
    table-figures-exponent = 1000,
    table-figures-integer = 1000,
    table-figures-uncertainty = 1000,
    table-figures-decimal = 1000,
    table-sign-mantissa,
    table-sign-exponent,
    table-auto-round
  }
  \begin{tabular}{
    S
    S
    S
    S
  }
  0.2 & 0.6903200460356393 & 0.625 & -6.532004603563935e-2 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there a fix?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37900/pgfplot-consistent-number-format and my comments there. (As you are the second person to raise this, I will move it up my 'to do' list a bit!)

Comment: [EDIT: Joseph did.] I suspect that Joseph Wright will chip in soon to explain what is going on more precisely. I think that the reason is that at some stage in the processing Siunitx uses floating points from `l3fp`, which currently only supports 9 (10?) digit numbers, and barfs when the decimal part has more digits than that (at an even lower level you have a TeX error: the decimal part is >2^{31}). I'm slowly working on an update to l3fp which would use more IEEE-854 compliant 16 digit mantissas and would simply round when the input has too many decimals. Not sure when that'll be done.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Actually, the rounding code does not use `l3fp` (the calculation stuff for angles does, for obvious reasons). The issue with the rounding code is that I essentially need to do a 'big int' comparison rather than `\int_compare:nNnTF` in some places to allow completely arbitrary amounts of digits.

Comment: @Joseph Actually, reading the comments you link to, I realize I'm wrong here. But would it make sense on the long term to use the rounding function from l3fp? That would restrict the mantissa to 16 digits, unfortunately, so not good for high-precision measurements of \alpha in a couple of years I guess. [Again, our comments crossed.]

Comment: You might be able to do something with `\pdftex_strcmp:D` here, after normalizing the numbers to be of the same length. Although, I guess that here you only care about the first digit, and the special case of half-round-up/down/even

Comment: A fix for this issue is in hand, and will be sent to CTAN once I have fully tested it (tomorrow). I notice that your input is not going to work, though, as you have misunderstood the way that table formatting works with `siunitx`. For example, `table-figures-integer = 1000` reserves space for _1000_ digits before the decimal place. I assume you want `table-figures-integer = 4` for four digits, _i.e._ up to `9999.`...

Comment: @JosephWright Can this be closed as "too localized"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest `siunitx` release (try v2.4j or later), although your `table-figures-exponent = 1000` will fail. Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{
    table-format = -1.3e-1,
    table-number-alignment = center,
    table-auto-round
  }
  \begin{tabular}{
    S
    S
    S
    S
  }
  0.2 & 0.6903200460356393 & 0.625 & -6.532004603563935e-2 \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```