# siunitx number too big when trying to round with scientific-notation = fixed

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to to round numbers in latex in a way, such that 1.23456e-10 rounded to two places becomes zero and not 1.23e-10.

One solution  with siunitx is

```
\num[round-mode=places,scientific-notation = fixed,fixed-exponent = 0 ,round-precision = 2]{1.23456e-6}
```

But if the digits get too many (>10) it fails, with the the error message

```
! Number too big.
```

As explained in [siunitx number too big when trying to round](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41663/siunitx-number-too-big-when-trying-to-round)

the command

```
\num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=2]{1.0123456789012e-6}
```

had the same problems, which are fixed now.

But, if I add scientific-notation = fixed, then the error reappears.

Does anybody know a fix for that problem?

Comment: I'd suggest reporting it in the bug tracker (https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issues) :-) I have a couple of other issues to look at, so this should be doable by the weekend.

Comment: @Joseph: I did. Would be great to see that fixed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bug fixed in source, CTAN update later today.

Answer (score 8):

Fixed in the current release of `siunitx` (v2.5c):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num
  [
    round-mode          = places,
    scientific-notation = fixed,
    fixed-exponent      = 0,
    round-precision     = 2
  ]{1.2345678901234567890e-6}

\end{document}
```