# siunitx number too big when trying to round with round-half = even

Tags: siunitx

I was trying to round numbers with siunitx and got the following error:

> Number too big \num{0.125555555555}

The problem occured when I changed the `round-half` parameter to `even`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2, round-half = up}% this works
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2, round-half = even}% this fails

\begin{document}
\num{0.125555555555}
\end{document}
```

I found similar questions here:

- [siunitx: Number too big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350940/siunitx-number-too-big?rq=1)
- [siunitx number too big when trying to round](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41663/siunitx-number-too-big-when-trying-to-round)
- [siunitx number too big when trying to round with scientific-notation = fixed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54098/siunitx-number-too-big-when-trying-to-round-with-scientific-notation-fixed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But it always says this problem should be fixed and one should update their version of `siunitx`, but I am already on the current version:

> Package: siunitx 2018/05/17 v2.7s A comprehensive (SI) units package

Comment: Yeah .. fixed in development version which I keep wanting to release ...

Comment: @JosephWright I updated siunitx to the current version "2.7u 2020-01-15", but I still get the same error "Number too big", when using `round-half = even`.